# Material Chip input widget can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, material-components-android, android-chips

I'm trying to make a ChipInput in my Android App after i've created my layout with a AutoCompleteEditText and a ChipGroup to which i'm adding the dynamically created Chip i get the following error in stacktrace:

> E/ThemeUtils: View class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip is an
> AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme
> (or descendant).
>
> The style on this component requires your app theme to be
> Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

The issue is that my Theme is yet set to Material but i still get that error, i've tried even to set the theme programmatically to the Chip but still having that error.

Here is the code where i add the chip programmatically

```
private fun addChipToGroup(person: String, chipGroup: ChipGroup) {
    val chip = Chip(applicationContext)
    chip.text = person
    chip.isCloseIconVisible = true

    // necessary to get single selection working
    chip.isClickable = true
    chip.isCheckable = false
    chipGroup.addView(chip as View)
    chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener { chipGroup.removeView(chip as View) }
}
```

And the app crash at the first line of that method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
val chip = Chip(applicationContext)
```

The Application context **doesn't have** your app theme.
You have to use a themed context like an `Activity`.

Comment: changed it with this@ActivityName and that's working now